# Lemme tell you 'bout this drama

Tags: cipher, rhyme, story

**(I apologise in advance for what is probably the dumbest tale you will read all week)**

Lemme tell you 'bout this drama
Check it out 'fore it decays.
This guy speak like Dalai Lama
Some girl's life done gone sideways.
Now don't be jelly
Of what I'm 'bout to telly!

> What ones sync roof VD. Purely reef, they or SHONE. Nu, rail or terra URL?

What's the story?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "story" is ...

> ... described in the poem. A terse version is encoded in the block-quoted sentences:

*Lemme tell you 'bout this drama*
*Check it out 'fore it decays.*
*This guy speak like Dalai Lama*

> Jung barf flap ebbs IQ.

*Some girl's life done gone sideways.*

> Cheryl errs, gurl be FUBAR.

*Now don't be jelly*
*Of what I'm 'bout to telly!*

> Ah, envy be green HEY?

Come again?

> The cipher that is used here is one of the simpler, but also one of the more popular ones. [It's Rot-13](http://www.rot13.com/). The gimmick of this story is that all the words can be rot-13'd into other words. Some of these words [are good friends](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52685/an-unfortunate-conundrum-involving-extremes), indeed. `:)`

Comment: Woohoo! If I'd seen the other one, maybe I would have stated that anyone could answer but you haha. One thing you missed (perhaps just didn't mention) was that "decays" was a hint for the cipher :)

Comment: +14 Z Bruz  [bar zber](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30311/half-an-awful-haiku)