# Riddle in Thirteen Lines!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> It loves to twist and turn,
> A mystery that men seek to learn.
> I don't doubt its swag,
> It can make an ant nag.
> It takes one so far,
> And builds a nice bar.
> It's powers can be seen,
> When it transforms a barren terra green.
> Never does it fail,
> When it makes one envy for rail.
> It's cryptic, not so complex,
> A weak clerk is now a strong Pyrex.
> It asks you, "What am I?"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is:

> the cipher **[rot-13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)** (i.e. a Caesar shift of 13 letters, so that A becomes N, B becomes O, C becomes P, etc.) commonly used here on Puzzling to hide information in comments.
>
>  This is hinted at by the use of *thirteen* lines in the riddle itself (and the title).

*It loves to twist and turn,*
*A mystery that men seek to learn.*

> rot-13 is a cipher, i.e. a way to disguise or *twist* your writing, to make your words *mysterious*.

*I don't doubt its swag,*
*It can make an ant nag.*

> ANT becomes NAG (and vice versa) in rot-13.

*It takes one so far,*
*And builds a nice bar.*

> ONE becomes BAR (and vice versa) in rot-13.

*It's powers can be seen,*
*When it transforms a barren terra green.*

> TERRA becomes GREEN (and vice versa) in rot-13.

*Never does it fail,*
*When it makes one envy for rail.*

> ENVY becomes RAIL (and vice versa) in rot-13.

*It's cryptic, not so complex,*

> It may appear mysterious but is still a relatively straightforward cipher to decrypt.

*A weak clerk is now a strong Pyrex.*

> CLERK becomes PYREX (and vice versa) in rot-13.

*It asks you "What am I?"*

Well, or does it in fact ask...

> "Jung nz V?"!

Comment: Aha! Gbb dhvpx! :D

Comment: @Techidiot Ha, well the use of 'terra' strongly reminded me of [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30311/half-an-awful-haiku) from many years ago... :)

Comment: Oops, Tom beat me to it. Should have checked and skipped Terra haha :D Well done anyhow :)